# Log4j vs. println for simple convenience program

Tags: java, log4j

I wrote a little java program (50-60 lines) to help with my own development. It is **invoked from the command line** and basically downloads some files and decrypts them. It was not part of any product. I thought it might be useful to other developers in my group, so I submitted it for a code review. The comment came back that I need **to change the `System.out.println`-s to log4j.**

The output consists of the name of each file downloaded and message when it completes.

**Is this overkill? I think it is.**

Comment: @Hemant Metalia: Is this format normal?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei i just wanted to highlight important points in the question

Comment: This probably more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're asking for an opinion, which will probably get flagged for closure, but meanwhile I agree, println is perfectly applicable. Debugging and info messages, however, normally are sent to System.err rather than System.out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to reuse your code you will want to use a logger of some sort. If you're going to use a logger I'd recommend using [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) instead of log4j. This will allow some downstream developer using your code to use whatever logging framework they want that implements or has a binding for the SLF4J API (log4j, java.util.logging, logback, etc).

If you don't care about anyone reusing your code, and this is a standalone product, then yes it is probably overkill.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the reuse factor. But @user1166233, definitely use Log4J over SLF4J.

Comment: Are you aware of any command line programs that use logging for stdout and stderr? It does not seem to make sense to print a couple of file names and completion message. I don't expect anyone to use this program exactly as I wrote it. I just thought I could save other people the work of having to rewrite something simmilar from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you print to System.out will go to "standard out",you can redirect it to a file for further analysis but that is very inflexible.

You cannot filter what goes to standard out if you use System.out... everything will be printed. By using any logging framework like [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/),[Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) or you can use log4j, you can set different logging levels.

Basically you don't want to see every debug message. You can set various logging level like `WARNING`,`DEBUG`, `INFO` with the help of a logger.

Comment: sure you can filter what goes to System.out. that's what filters do, read from stdin and write to stdout.

Comment: What i meant was it is more convenient with `loggers`. Like if i change logging level to warn my debug and info message will not be displayed anymore.So, now i have more control over my logging.

Comment: OK, understood. I use logging where applicable, but for simple command-line scripts usually prefer stdout/stderr.

Comment: I too prefer stdout/stderr for small applications.But i think it is a good practice to use loggers.

Comment: I should have added that I don't expect anybody to use this program exactly as I wrote it. It is tailored for the problem I am currently working on. I do think others will need something similar and would benefit by not having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

**Probably is (overkill), but depends.**

When you say that the software was made for your own development but then you released it to your group of developers you are actually saying that the software originally had a function and now has another function. Being the primary function serve you and the secondary (and final function) serve the group/community.

****If in your group of developers there are code standards***, and I sure hope there are, and if one of the standards is using log4j to log everything, that by all means you should go with the standards.*